# start point to play audio/video content from IOS device to Apple TV

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, airplay

I m looking for a good tutorial as a start point to play content from an IOS App (Ipad/Iphone, objective C with IOS SDK 5.0 ) to Apple TV , but it looks like Apple doesn't provide that kind of sample (or maybe I miss it) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search pulled up the following:

- http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_airplay/

Couldn't really find any other good ones... Will require more digging.

Answer (score 0):

To play content from Apple's iPad, iPhone or iPod on Apple's TV you need airplay.

All you need is to connect both devices on same wifi connection.

Comment: This does not relate to the question - He's asking about software development, not how to use the devices.